# Create one large image out of many small ones? LÖVE

Tags: lua, love2d

Is it posible to create a drawable object out of some other drawable objects? And How would I do it?

Comment: _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: I've allready found an answer @MickyDuncan

Comment: Excellent.  Just saying for the future.  Welcome to SO by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Canvas](https://love2d.org/wiki/Canvas) and draw the smaller images into it.

```
bigger = love.graphics.newCanvas(100, 100)
bigger:renderTo(function() 
      -- draw images here using love.graphics.draw etc...

      end)
```

and then later use the canvas instead of the smaller images:

```
love.graphics.draw(bigger)
```